# Error executing Dataflow task from Cloud composer: Log file is not found

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

In one of our Cloud Composer/Airflow jobs, we invoke a number of DataflowTemplateOperator jobs (JDBC to BigQuery) to bring in data from a postgres instance into BigQuery. We are intermittently experiencing an error:

```
*** Log file is not found: gs://us-east1-xxxxxxx-prod-cfaffd18-bucket/logs/xxxxxx-dag-daily-job/xxxxxxx/2022-01-29T07:30:00+00:00/1.log. The task might not have been executed or worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g. was evicted)
*** 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/us-east1-xxxxxx-cfaffd18-bucket/o/logs%2Fprod-xxxxxx-dag-daily-job%2Fdw_load_locations%2F2022-01-29T07%3A30%3A00%2B00%3A00%2F1.log?alt=media: No such object: us-east1-xxxxxx-cfaffd18-bucket/logs/xxxxxx-dag-daily-job/xxxxxxx/2022-01-29T07:30:00+00:00/1.log: ('Request failed with status code', 404, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)
```

Environment:
Composer version: 1.17.7
Aitflow version: 2.1.4

The jobs complete successfully upon retrying.

Is this a known issue? Looking for some guidance on how to debug this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a known issue, this is supposed to be fixed to the most recent version of Cloud Composer, furthermore you can set the notifications on to keep a track on this issue that is affecting you at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211620420 .

Comment: Still have this issue on composer-1.17.7-airflow-2.1.4. Planning to upgrade to composer-1.17.9-airflow-2.1.4 and see what happens.

This started happening last weekend, prior to this, the particular environment and DAG was running fine for over a month.

I added the comment on the issuetracker as well. 

Thanks.

Comment: Issue appears resolved after upgrading to composer-1.17.9-airflow-2.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

We get rid of this error after we increased vCPUs for the workers. It turned out that "missing log file" is not the problem but the consequence of the real problem which is:

"The task might not have been executed or worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g. was evicted)"